# 53. Isn't there a discount for ordering in bulk? (A) Yes, but very few. (B) No, none whatsoever. (C) No, it isn't

Tags: exam-questions

> 53. Isn't there a discount for ordering in bulk?
>
> (A) Yes, but very few.
>   (B) No, none whatsoever.
>   (C) No, it isn't.

This question appears in my test, and I'm confused with the answer because I thought the right answer is c but then it is wrong. Why it is wrong?

Comment: "tag questions" normally reflect the actual form of the preceding ***real*** question. So in your case, the idiomatically natural responses are *No, **there isn't*** or *Yes, **there is***. But it's a stupid test, because if the answerer specifically wanted to make the point that although there ***are*** "some discounts" *(**plural**)*, he can't naturally reflect the form of the question as asked (and obviously the *questioner* can't know in advance whether he should be asking about the possibility of ***a*** discount, or ***multiple*** discounts).

Comment: What was the indicated correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: using the form of answer C, the correct grammar would be: "No, there isn't."

The presence of the term "is there" in the question means it is asking whether a discount exists. The correct response should use the same "is there" form to affirm or reject the existence, or perhaps a similar phrase. "No, none whatsoever." is such a similar phrase.

The phrase: "No, it isn't." is used to say the object (*it*) is not *something*. For example:

```
Is the discount available today?
No, it isn't.
```

The response is actually short for "No it isn't available today." Because the question does not ask whether the discount is *something*, but asks whether it exists, the answer cannot merely be "No it isn't."